# assert type of a function with two arguments

Tags: haskell

Basically, I'm doing something like

```
c = a&&b
```

where both a, b are Bool.

Here is what I wrote:

```
c = a&&b (Bool a, Bool b) -> Bool
```

But obviously it doesn't work. Can anyone tells what's the problem?

Comment: I think it would be best to start learning syntax at learnyouahaskell.com at least that is where I have started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the type on a separate line, like this:

```
c :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
c a b = a && b
```

Really, though, you could also skip the arguments:

```
c :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
c = (&&)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't understand the syntax Bool -> Bool -> Bool. Doesn't "->" mean return?

Comment: the syntax means that everything before the last arrow `->` is argument -i.e. 2 x `Bool` and the one after the last arrow is the result type - in this case also `Bool`.

Comment: @melpomene I think this is what the OP intended to write - it is a bit unclear though

Comment: @RyanZhao Strictly speaking, `->` itself is an operator; it maps a single argument type to a single return type. In this case, the argument type is `Bool`, and the return type is *another* function type, `Bool -> Bool`. Haskell functions are [curried](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).

Answer (score 4):

```
c = a&&b (Bool a, Bool b) -> Bool
```

This is a syntax error. `a && b (Bool a, Bool b) -> Bool` is treated as a single expression. If I were a compiler, I'd complain about `->` because that's not valid there. (Subsequent errors: A `Bool` constructor is not in scope and `b` is not a function.)

If you want to express that `c` is a `Bool`:

```
c :: Bool
c = a && b
```

If you want to express that the expression `a&&b` has type `Bool`:

```
c = a && b :: Bool
```

---

However, your title says "*type of a function with two arguments*" but your `c` isn't a function (it has no arguments). If you intended `a` and `b` to be arguments, it would look like:

```
c a b = a && b
```

or

```
c = \a b -> a && b
```

In this case a type signature would look like:

```
c :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

This is because `->` in a type is right associative: `Bool -> Bool -> Bool` means `Bool -> (Bool -> Bool)`, i.e. `c` is a function taking a `Bool` and returning a function (which takes `Bool` and returns a `Bool`).

---

`c :: (Bool a, Bool b) -> Bool` is wrong on multiple levels. The most immediate problem is that `Bool a` is the syntax for passing an argument to a parametrized type (as in `Maybe Int` or `Set String`), but `Bool` takes no arguments (and if it did, then `... -> Bool` would be missing an argument).

Second, types and expressions live in different "worlds". The variables `a` and `b` are type variables here. They're unrelated to `a` and `b` in the following expression.

Third, `(X, Y)` is tuple syntax. It's possible to define `c` to take a single argument (which is a tuple of two `Bool`s):

```
c :: (Bool, Bool) -> Bool
c (a, b) = a && b
```

... but this is not what's normally done in Haskell. The convention is to prefer curried functions (the functions-returning-functions thing described above), where you effectively have `Arg1 -> Arg2 -> Arg3 -> ... -> Result`.